# JQ Array Index String

Tags: bash, unix, jq

I have a Json file for which I need to build an insert statement in SQL based if the key exists in a flat file. I can have multiple records in Json and the keys may be changed for each record overtime.

The keys are stored in a text file on OS and it contains simple rows of keys valid for insert generation. I will have to match keys from JSON and get value to build statement like:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (key1, key2, key5, key8) VALUES 
("key1_Value","key2_Value","key5_Value","key8_Value")
```

My approach is to process json in a loop - by using

```
jq -r '.value[].UnitTypes[]|to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' test.json
```

Problem comes when I am tried to access with array index number from my incremental variable as every record may have changed keys :

```
i=1
jq -r --arg counter $i '.value[].UnitTypes[$counter]|to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' test.json

jq: error (at test.json:1): Cannot index array with string "1"
```

What I am missing here.

Thanks for your help.

My Json File:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "Sample Text Grid Context",
  "@odata.count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "ListingId": "DUMMY_001",
      "UnitTypes": [
        {
          "RAN_GarageDescription": "1 Car Garage - Att,1 Space",
          "RAN_MiscIncluded": "Air Conditioning,Dishwasher,Range/Oven,Refrigerator,Wood Burning FP",
          "RAN_OtherRoom1Desc": "Den/Office",
          "RAN_OtherRoom2Desc": "Rec Room",
          "UnitTypeActualRent": 975,
          "RAN_HalfBaths": "1",
          "RAN_FullBaths": "1",
          "RAN_Location": "Left/1706",
          "RAN_OtherRoom1Fin": "10x13",
          "RAN_OtherRoom2Fin": "10x12",
          "RAN_VacancyType": "Rent",
          "RAN_ElectricPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "RAN_HeatPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "RAN_Bedroom1": "13x12",
          "RAN_Bedroom2": "13x12",
          "RAN_DiningRoom": "10x10",
          "RAN_Kitchen": "12x10",
          "RAN_Level": "Main",
          "RAN_LivingGreatRoom": "20x12",
          "UnitTypeBedsTotal": 2,
          "UnitTypeType": "Unit 1",
          "RAN_SqFtFin": "1465",
          "RAN_WaterPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "UnitTypeKey": "RAN50270568Group_1"
        },
        {
          "RAN_GarageDescription": "1 Car Garage - Detached,1 Space",
          "RAN_MiscIncluded": "Air Conditioning,Dishwasher,Range/Oven,Wood Burning FP,Refrigerator",
          "RAN_Bedroom1": "12x12",
          "RAN_Bedroom2": "12x12",
          "RAN_Bedroom3": "12x10",
          "RAN_DiningRoom": "10x10",
          "RAN_Kitchen": "12x10",
          "RAN_Level": "Main",
          "RAN_LivingGreatRoom": "20x12",
          "RAN_Location": "Right/1704",
          "RAN_VacancyType": "Rent",
          "RAN_WaterPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "RAN_LeaseExpDate": "2023-07-31",
          "RAN_HalfBaths": "0",
          "UnitTypeActualRent": 1145,
          "RAN_ElectricPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "RAN_HeatPaidBy": "Tenant",
          "RAN_FamilyRoom": "23x10",
          "RAN_FullBaths": "2",
          "UnitTypeBedsTotal": 3,
          "UnitTypeType": "Unit 2",
          "RAN_SqFtFin": "1442",
          "UnitTypeKey": "RAN50270568Group_2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired SQL commands (no description) for that JSON.

Comment: @Cyrus I dont care about SQL Statement because it would be variable based on the Keys. The real issue with me is to process the json and get rid of Cannot index array with string "1" error.

Comment: Because of quoting issues for SQL (and potential disaster if not using them), consider using something more capable than jq+Bash.

Comment: @TahirKhalil You need `$counter` to be a number, not a string. Therefore, use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.

Comment: @pmf thank you - this is what I was missing. --argjson and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.UnitTypes[$counter | tonumber]
```

instead of

```
.UnitTypes[$counter]
```

The problem is that $counter argument come to jq as string, but array index must be number.

Part of jq manual:

- `--arg name value`

This option passes a value to the jq program as a predefined
variable. If you run jq with `--arg foo bar`, then `$foo` is
available in the program and has the value `"bar"`. Note that
`value` will be treated as a string, so `--arg foo 123` will
bind `$foo` to `"123"`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @knittl I did this because of manual has a highlight, for better understanding. Anyway, I replace image by text version.

Comment: Text (and especially Markdown) has highlighting too :) Now, if the jq manual could be linked, that would make this answer even better. Also worth mentioning that `--arg` creates a string variable, but `--argjson` can be used to create variables of type number, array, or object.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
jq -r --arg counter $i '.value[].UnitTypes[$counter] | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' test.json
```

[`--arg` treats its values as strings](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#invoking-jq), so you end up executing the equivalent of:

```
jq -r '.value[].UnitTypes["1"] | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' test.json
```

but `"1"` is not a valid array index (whereas `1` is).

To pass a variable as a JSON-encoded value, use `--argjson` instead:

```
i=1
jq -r --argjson counter "$i" '.value[].UnitTypes[$counter] | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' test.json
```